# Statistical significance of counts per month

Tags: time-series, statistical-significance, count-data

I have a dataset of events over time. Commonly, we are interested in how many events per month and how many events per year. Here is a dummy dataset:

| Year | Month | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2019 | Jan | 2 |
| 2019 | Feb | 1 |
| 2019 | Mar | 2 |
| 2019 | Apr | 3 |
| 2019 | May | 3 |
| 2019 | Jun | 1 |
| 2019 | Jul | 2 |
| 2019 | Aug | 2 |
| 2019 | Sep | 1 |
| 2019 | Oct | 1 |
| 2019 | Nov | 2 |
| 2019 | Dec | 2 |
| 2020 | Jan | 1 |
| 2020 | Feb | 2 |
| 2020 | Mar | 3 |
| 2020 | Apr | 3 |
| 2020 | May | 2 |
| 2020 | Jun | 1 |
| 2020 | Jul | 1 |
| 2020 | Aug | 3 |
| 2020 | Sep | 2 |
| 2020 | Oct | 1 |
| 2020 | Nov | 2 |
| 2020 | Dec | 3 |
| 2021 | Jan | 1 |
| 2021 | Feb | 1 |
| 2021 | Mar | 2 |
| 2021 | Apr | 3 |
| 2021 | May | 4 |
| 2021 | Jun | 9 |
| 2021 | Jul | 5 |
| 2021 | Aug | 4 |
| 2021 | Sep | 5 |
| 2021 | Oct | 3 |
| 2021 | Nov | 3 |
| 2021 | Dec | 3 |

The questions I would like to answer are things like:

- Is 2021 statistically significantly different from the previous year?
- Is 2021 statistically significantly different from all of the previous years? (this may be more complicated as there is a generally a creep up in numbers as the years go on)
- is June 2021 statistically significantly different from June 2020?

I imagine this is relatively simple, but I also relatively poor with stats. I have this image in my head of a trend line through the data with points and error bars to pick up any which are outliers, but I am not sure what kind of test or calculation I would need in order to construct that. Any suggestions will be much appreciated and thank you in advance.

Comment: It depends, do you want to compare mean values or trends?